# Why waste resources by having hosts kill each other when no players are around?

Tags: westworld-2016

In episode three we see a scene where Teddy and Delores shoot the bandits in their storyline even when no one's around.  What is the purpose of this?  We know that it costs time and resources to restore dead hosts so why not skip that part if no one's around to see it?

Comment: @Paulie_D - The same day repeats because it's a ride. They go around, then they go around again. Occasionally a guest steps into (or through) the story that's playing out. Just like a fairground runs [empty rollercoasters](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wLQ2oZXyuDE) because it's easier to simply allow the system to run on auto than to have the staff attending to it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is covered in the [second episode](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4562758/?ref_=ttep_ep2). In short, the Head of Programming (Bernard Lowe) feels that continual interaction allows the hosts to become more realistic.

> **Theresa**: *Although, ironically, your creations never shut up. **They're always talking to each other, even when there are no guests around.***
>
> **Bernard:** *They're always trying to error correct. Make themselves more human. **When they talk to each other, it's a way of
>   practicing.***

This evidently includes playing out storylines. You'll note that most of those seem to involve hanging and punches (which one assumed are easily repaired) rather than gunplay and knifework (which require more intensive fixes).

On top of that, in the [first episode](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4227538/) we learn that the characters themselves are involved in over "*100 different interconnected narractives"*. Having a host turn themselves off would mean that there would be significant knock-on effects when they *weren't where they were supposed to be at the time they were supposed to be there*.

> **Lee:** *Are you fucking kidding me? That's 200 hosts spread across a dozen active storylines.*
>
> ...
>
> *We sell complete immersion in 100 interconnected narratives.*

---

There's also the possibility that a guest may be viewing the action from a distance or through a window. Having the hosts immobile when there's no-one around would seem odd if observed from far away.

Comment: Talking I can understand (I remember that scene too) but shooting and killing seems to be an excessive cost for fine tuning heuristics.

Comment: @z- - The plotlines are (largely) fixed. If a guest steps in, the plot doesn't change unless they kill/screw something.

Comment: That makes sense.  Thanks

Comment: @z- - When they turn on the [Earthquake Ride](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5JswjbEgV0Y&feature=youtu.be&t=2m17s) in the morning and run it empty to check everything's working, do you think there's a special button that turns off the smoke and water to stop it being wasted, or do they just run it as normal?

Comment: no but I doubt they'll run the ride if no one's on it other than for the initial safety check  ;)

Comment: The comment about talking versus killing has a point. It's still a waste of resources since it takes several humans some amount of effort to repair each killed host. Why not just have the hosts go into an alternate activity until a human arrives?